# How to share access of a private child to same access as parent, without using master-detail?

Tags: security, apex-managed-sharing, owd, apex-sharing

Given my object relationship below, how (without using master-detail between media and account) would I solve the need to share Media__c in a private Media__c model such that access to Media mimics/mirrors access to its related Account?  Note: I won't accept the answer "use a master detail between account and media" because the other (non-security) implications of using master-detail do not fit my need.

[image]

**Read/Write: Allows users with at least Read/Write access to the Master record to create, edit, or delete related Detail records.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

The only other method for sharing custom objects that may suit your needs is [Apex-Based Sharing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm). However, it's not perfect, because you can't create triggers on sharing tables to replicate the rules appropriately, so you'd have to run a scheduled process every once in a while to sync up the tables. In other words, users will not have real-time access to the records. Despite your objections about not using master-detail relationships, it's the only way you're going to correctly manage security without writing any code.